# Triple Cover of the Riemann Sphere

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I have the triple branched covering $X$ of $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ defined by $y^{3}=x^{6}-1$. I want to show the following:

(i) The canonical embedding $\phi: X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{3}$ can be given in affine coordinates by $\phi(x,y)=(x,x^{2}, y)$.

(ii) Find irreducible quadric and cubic hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$ that contain $\phi(X)$.

I am rather lost on how to approach this. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks very much.

Comment: Hi! Is this homework?

Comment: Hi! Nope, but I believe it is from a previous homework assignment of a friend of mine. We've both had trouble figuring it out :(